# How to store images in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I started an application where I show my products to my clients and I need to show them the product image, so I started to see how to use google cloud and I read something about filestore but I'm not sure if it's the best solution for me, also I didn't understand the way google charge for that service, in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/pricing) explains that 1GB per month it will charge me $0.20 cents, Can someone explain me this?, Is there a better solution for this?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My gut is saying that you are likely going to want to use Google Cloud Store ... see:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Comment: I read about cloud storage and I see that for me is the best solution, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Maybe take a few minutes to answer your own question for future readers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Filestore is to create fully managed NFS file servers on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for use with applications running on Compute Engine virtual machines (VMs) instances or Kubernetes Engine clusters.
You can use the Cloud Filestore Editor and Cloud Filestore Viewer roles to grant Cloud Filestore permissions to users.

Cloud Filestore pricing is based on 3 component:

1 - [Service tier](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/tiers): Whether your instance uses Standard or Premium tier.

```
Standard Tier : $0.000274
```

> offers moderate performance of
>   approximately 120 megabytes (MB) per second read/write throughput.

```
Premium Tier : $0.000411
```

> offers increased performance of approximately 240 MB per second
>   read/write throughput.

2 - Instance size: The size of your instance.

> The minimum Standard tier instance size is 1 terabyte (TB) and the minimum Premium tier instance size is 2.5 TB. The maximum instance size for either tier is 63.9 TB

3 - [Region](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/regions): The location where your instance is provisioned

Here some Pricing [examples](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/pricing#pricing_examples).

If you want just to share a file or image as you described, a [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) is an easy way to share a bucket.

As part of the [Google Cloud Platform Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/), Cloud Storage provides resources that are free to use up to specific limits.

Here is a Pricing [examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing-examples) as well.